# A trouble with automation of Windows RDP through console

Tags: python, winapi, rdp

A brief description of my problem:

1.
My Jenkins job is required to establish an RDP connection to another machine to perform some activities.

2.
Until recently, the default password was maintained between sessions. But now some settings have changed, and the password needs to be reentered by hand each time I creating a new RDP session.

I prepared a short python script interacting with the Windows gui via the win32gui package.

I built a stand alone executable file from this script using the pyinstaller.
And finally I added a call to this executable file directly to the job.

Somethig like that:

```
while attempts:
    security_window_title = "Windows Security"
    try:
        hwnd_credentials = win32gui.FindWindow(0, security_window_title)

        window_controls = []
        win32gui.EnumChildWindows(hwnd_credentials, collect_window_control, None)

        focus_on_window(hwnd_credentials)
        sleep(0.5)
        prev_user_login = window_controls[2]["hwnd"]

        x = int(window_controls[1]["x"] + 80)
        y = int(window_controls[1]["y"] + 20)

        click(x, y)
        type_message(password)

        ok_button = window_controls[6]["hwnd"]
        push_button(ok_button)

    except win32gui.error:
        sleep(1)
        attempts -= 1
        if not attempts:
            raise RuntimeError("Can't interact with window: {}.".format(security_window_title))
    else:
        break

while attempts:
    sleep(timeout)
    attempts -= 1
    if check_connection_started():
        break

    if check_certificate_errors():
        for control in window_controls[::-1]:
            if control["text"] == "&Yes":
                push_button(control["hwnd"])

    if not attempts:
        raise RuntimeError("Connection not established.")
```

3.
This would not be a problem when script running from the job working with the fully functional Windows ui. I can find a window in which my script is supposed to specify a password using the win32gui python package. I can generate all the appropriate keyboard events to enter a password.

Using RDP via console provides me a very strange set of windows-like objects which I can not interact with using the win32gui python package the same way as with ordinary windows. For example, I do locate a window with non zero hwnd and with text property equal to "Remote Desktop Connection". But I can't focus on such a window using the basic method win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd). This leads to an unnamed  win32gui exception.

Is there any possibility to transfer the password to the desired control of the desired window-like structure, so that the job does not interrupt its execution?

Thank you so much for any help.

Comment: Use [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.github.io/) with `backend="uia"`.

Answer (score 0):

I can focus on both "Remote Desktop Connection" and "Windows Security" with `win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)`. 
Sample code:

```
import win32api
import win32gui
import win32con
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

def main():
    Remote = "Remote Desktop Connection"
    Security = "Windows Security"
    try:
        hwnd_Remote = win32gui.FindWindow(0, Remote)
        print(hwnd_Remote)
        win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd_Remote,win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL)
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd_Remote)
        keyboard = Controller()
        keyboard.type('ipaddress')
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
        time.sleep(3)
        hwnd_Security = win32gui.FindWindow(0, Security)
        print(hwnd_Security)
        win32gui.ShowWindow(hwnd_Security,win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL)
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd_Security)
        keyboard.type('password')
        keyboard.press(Key.enter)
        keyboard.release(Key.enter)
    except win32gui.error:
        raise RuntimeError("Can't interact with window: {}.".format(Remote))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Make sure that the foreground process did not disable calls to the `SetForegroundWindow` function. Add the [`LockSetForegroundWindow(LSFW_UNLOCK)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-locksetforegroundwindow) or [`AllowSetForegroundWindow(ASFW_ANY)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-allowsetforegroundwindow) to enable the call of `SetForegroundWindow`.